# UIView / SubView causing bug with UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I have a ViewController with a UIVIew covering the layout.
I then use the following (edited) code:

```
UIView *stars = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(starX,starY, starSize, starSize)];
stars.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:stars];
```

Calling this method (specifically the last line) causes all my other UIImageViews on the screen to "reset" back to their original starting positions. I would appreciate any advice on what my issue might be.

Please note I am very early in my programming learning so be gentle with descriptions and language if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain the "to "reset" back to their original"?

Comment: did you use imageView.transform to move the other images?

Comment: I Think starX and startY positions are not incrementing

Comment: @DaSilva - I have a main character in the game who moves aroundy dynamically and everytime the [self.view addSubview:stars]; line is run it resets his x and y co-ordinates to it's original position.

Comment: @Ramesh Muthe - they do increment but elsewhere in the code. They themselves though should not move anyway

Comment: @SrinivasanN I would but there is so much code I don't want to flood the thread. Is there a portion or aspect you think could be most relevant?